# Setting the TensorFlow is_training training flag (in batch_normalize)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to use batch normalization in TensorFlow and came across this `batch_normalize` function on the GitHub: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e8494eacfb552c4bf33c15657238aabecc2a6343/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/ops/batch_norm_ops.py)

I noticed that there is a specific flag to check whether we are training or not. However, I'm not familiar with how to set this flag to True or False, and is it standard to set this *particular* flag when training? The line that I am referring to is here:

`is_training = array_ops_.squeeze(ops.get_collection("IS_TRAINING"))`

**To summarize my question**: How do I set this flag to True/False so that I can use this `batch_normalize` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That function is part of scikit-flow a.k.a TF learn, not "base" TF - you can see how they set the flag in the estimator part of the library: [GitHub link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ec0552f1bc0e7c6ec6bd84ea1c3c92ff046d6d3c/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py)

It's the

```
self._graph.add_to_collection("IS_TRAINING", True)
```

part with `self._graph` being the TF graph that contains the batchnorm op.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it as part of the custom model function passed into `TensorFlowEstimator`, you can simply call `fit` so it will be in training. When you are calling `predict`, `batch_normalize` will be used in testing.

Note that those are automatically called by TensorFlow Learn (a.k.a Scikit Flow) so all you need to focus on is to provide your custom model function and pass that into `TensorFlowEstimator`.